# MySQL OSX Lion - cannot connect after restart

Tags: mysql, osx-lion

Just upgraded a MBP 2009 from Snow Leopard to Lion.  MySQL seems to be acting weird after the install.  I've tried this on almost ALL possible ways to install MySQL (XAMPP, AMPPS, Homebrew and the official 64-bit DMG from Mysql.com) and they all exhibit the same behavior.

The first start of MySQL (from all the packages above), everything is good.  I use SequelPro to connect so the connection is fairly basic => Host: 127.0.0.1, User: root, Password: [blank] *... (AMPPs is "mysql")*
I start/stop the MySQL server and everything seems to be ok.

The next step is to import a new database.  So create a database (UTF-8), click on the database and do IMPORT (using a .sql file).  Everything still works.  I stop the MySQL server and start it again.  A .pid file gets generated, the .err file looks correct.  I fire up SequelPro again and now it cannot connect to the MySQL server.  Doing a ps -ef | grep mysql shows that everything is fine (running process matches the .pid file).  I tried setting up the mysql.sock file to /tmp/mysql.sock (and other places) to no avail.

The funny thing is that this just started happening on OSX Lion -- and I've tried ALL the packages above.  The only way I have been able to work around it is to keep moving /Applications/XAMPP to the trash and re-installing and doing a new import and NOT shut down the MySQL server.  The minute I have to shut it down or reboot, I have to re-install XAMPP all over again.

Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem if you don't have a password for the "root" user (during install).  If you are in this position, this is the way to reset your password for root (set to something like 'a')

http://www.coolestguyplanet.net/how-to-change-the-mysql-root-password/

If using homebrew, this is the command to use:

/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.15/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables